# (Solaris10 grep) Regex to match different words

Tags: regex, grep, sh

In Solaris 10, I can't use grep properly. I just need a regex which can match a sentence containing "apple" or "banana",and I've been trying for an hour, but I can't make it work.

```
#!/bin/sh
# this is NOT bash
# grep usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

RESET='\033[0m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'

write() {
    message=$1

    if [ `echo $message | grep -c '^Success'` -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo "${GREEN}$message${RESET}"
    elif [ `echo $message | grep -c '(apple|banana)'` -gt 0 ]          # doesn't work
    then
        echo "${YELLOW}$message${RESET}"
    elif [ `echo $message | grep -c '^.*(apple|banana).*$'` -gt 0 ]    # neither
    then
        echo "${YELLOW}$message${RESET}"
    elif [ `echo $message | grep -c '/^.*(apple|banana).*$/'` -gt 0 ]  # neither
    then
        echo "${YELLOW}$message${RESET}"
    elif [ `echo $message | grep -c '^Error'` -gt 0 ]
    then
            echo "${RED}$message${RESET}"
    fi
}

write 'Success'
write 'Error'
write 'banana'
```

P.S. : it works very well if I need a regex for anything else, just not for apple OR banana

Comment: Assuming your version of `grep` supports it, you probably want `if echo "$message" | grep -q '^Success'; then`, etc. instead of capturing the output of `grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `grep` uses Basic RegEx (BRE) format. You can use `egrep` or `grep -E` to tell grep to use Extended RegEx (ERE) instead.

ERE identifies parenthesized subexpressions the way you've done in your question, i.e. `(..|..)`. However, BRE uses `\(..\|..\)`.

```
$ echo apple | grep -c '\(apple\|banana\)'
1
$ echo apple | grep -E -c '(apple|banana)'
1
```

Search for "Subexpression" in the [Solaris grep man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29043/regex-5.html#REFMAN5regex-5).

Either option will work for your tests, you just have to use the right dialect for your grep options .. or use the right grep options for your dialect.

---

Depending on your use case, you might want to consider using a `case` statement instead of grep.

```
case "$message" in
    Success*)          colour="$GREEN" ;;
    *apple*|*banana*)  colour="$YELLOW" ;;
    *plantain*)        colour="$YELLOW" ;;
    Error*)            colour="$RED" ;;
    *)                 colour="$RED"; message="UNKNOWN" ;;
esac

printf '%s%s%s\n' "$colour" "$message" "$RESET"
```

Note that the patterns in a case statement are handled using *Shell Patterns*, not regular expressions. Check the "File Name Generation" section of [`man sh`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/sh-1.html#scrolltoc) for details on the simplicity and limitations of this notation.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the pipe:

```
grep -c 'apple\|banana'
```

And you don't need the other stuff.

Comment: I'll try, but isn't it strange to escape the pipe ? I thought the pipe needed to be interpreted. Does it mean I should escape other regex symbols like parethesis or braces ?

Comment: No. And yes. Kinda. grep works with BREs by default. If you escape a BRE metacharacter it will become a literal. In some greps (e.g. GNU) if you escape ERE metacharacters it will enable their ERE properties even when grep is running in BRE mode. Alterantively call grep with the `-E` argument and then it will use EREs instead of BREs and then you don't want to escape any metacharacters unless you want them all to be literals. So learn about BREs and EREs and grep options and then choose which characters to escape very carefully. Fortunately your problem is not a candidate for using grep anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `egrep` (extended grep) in order to use regular expressions with grep in the bourne shell.  I'm a little rusty though.

To test, launch the bourne shell:

```
/bin/sh
```

then type:

```
$ echo banana | grep -c '(apple|banana)'
0
$ echo banana | egrep -c '(apple|banana)'
1
```

Interesting, eh?  The first result is 0 as it is looking for the entire string of `'(apple|banana)'` thus your script fails.  egrep interprets the string as a regular expression thus it returns 1.

More testing:

```
$ echo apple | egrep -c '(apple|banana)'
1
$ echo Gabriel | egrep -c '(apple|banana)'
0
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell is an environment from which to call tools, not a tool to manipulate text. The general purpose UNIX text manipulation tool is awk. Therefore you should be writing an awk script, not a shell script, and it's incredibly simple:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function write(message, color) {
    if      ( message ~ /^Success/ )        { color = green }
    else if ( message ~ /^(apple|banana)/ ) { color = yellow }
    else if ( message ~ /^Error/ )          { color = red }
    print color message reset
}

BEGIN {
    reset  = "\033[0m"
    red    = "\033[0;31m"
    green  = "\033[0;32m"
    yellow = "\033[0;33m"

    write("Success")
    write("Error")
    write("banana")
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
Success
Error
banana
```

Trust me the output is colored correctly.

btw the default awk on Solaris (/bin/awk) is old, broken awk and should never be used by anyone for any reason. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or, less usefully, nawk).